# Find parameters for graph in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a graph in excel which I want to automatically create through VBA. Is there a way to figure out the parameters of the existing graph template that I have? For example, the line colors used (what they correspond to in VBA) and line type .. etc. So I can use them as parameters in VBA.

Comment: I recommend creating the same kind of excel graph by yourself but with Macro recording turned on. Once you feel the graph you built is equivalent to the graph that's there, you can stop recording. VBA is, at that time, already written for you. Tweak to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to figure out what Excel calls parameters, or what values correspond with colors, is:

1. Click the "Record Macros" button ([Record Macros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZGR0.png)) in the lower left hand corner of Excel
2. Create your graph the way you want it
3. Stop recording
4. Open the VBA editor with Alt+F11
5. Find the new macro (probably "Macro1" in "Module1"), and see if you can figure out what bits of code are the ones you want.

Note that this won't be the most efficient code, but it'll probably do what you want.